# Partition second drive in dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have probably a very simple question.

I have installed Windows 10 on my new computer and would like to Dual-boot. My setup is SSD + HDD where Windows is on SSD. I would like to split SSD and install Ubuntu on SSD too. The question is that, do I also need to split the second drive for Windows and Ubuntu or can I somehow keep it unbiased and acces the full memory from both?

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drive capacity is storage not memory.
Format it NTFS and turn off "Fast Startup" in Windows, then it can be accessed by both systems.

Since SSD life is dependent on the number of writes done to it. You should try to keep the files on the SSD limited to ones that rarely change.

Recommendations to increase SSD life:

- Keep the SSD for system files and data that you write once and just read; like movies and music.
- Make three partitions on the HDD. One ntfs for a share; second. ext4 for linux files that change often. And the third for linux swap.
- Windows frequently writes to the swapfile. The Windows swapfile and hiberfile should be placed on the HDD partition. In the system menu, you can tell Windows where to put the swapfile.
- Don't defrag the SSD partitions. Defragging Windows partitions result in many repeated writes as files are moved around. Since an SSD can access everywhere instantly, file fragmentation does not have the effect that it does in a HDD. If you have successfully limited the SSD to unchanging files, it won't need defragging anyway.